# Error 404, page displays correctly in the servers address, but not when I publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was thinking this may have been caused because one page was a copy of another that I then modified. However, the inherit properties are correct. When I access the page within Visual Studio or the visual studio file address in explorer (on build) the page opens fine. However, when I publish I get an error 404.0 stating "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
It then shows the physical path. I have confirmed that the file is there, in the file it should be. There are 8 total pages in this solution, all 6 others work.

Not sure which code to show, but here is all the code for one page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class EditRef : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=AVOKADB1; Initial Catalog=AvokaItemDev;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void btnPopulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comPopulate;
        String strPopulate;
        //Start Code from here
        //con.Open();
        //Query Coding for stem and old id
        strPopulate = "select * from  [references] where ref_code='" + searchRefTextBox.Text + "' or title = '" + searchTitleTextBox.Text + "'";
        comPopulate = new SqlCommand(strPopulate, con);
        SqlDataReader readerPopulate = comPopulate.ExecuteReader();
        if (readerPopulate.Read())
        {
            refCodeTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["ref_code"].ToString();
            titleTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["Title"].ToString();
            editionTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["Edition"].ToString();
            authorTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["Author"].ToString();
            publisherTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["Publisher"].ToString();
            yearPublishedTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["Year"].ToString();
            isbnTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["ISBN"].ToString();
            publishedDateTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["published_date"].ToString();
            existingMarketSegmentTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["market_segment_id"].ToString();
            notesTextBox.Text = readerPopulate["Notes"].ToString();
            readerPopulate.Close();

        }

        else readerPopulate.Close();
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdSubmit = new SqlCommand("Update [references] set ref_code = @Refcode, market_segment_id = (select distinct m.market_segment_id from market_segment m left join item_header h on m.market_segment_id = h.market_segment_id where m.market_segment_name = @MarketSegment), Title = @Title, Edition = @Edition, Author = @Author, Publisher = @Publisher, Year = @Year, ISBN = @ISBN, published_date = @PublishedDate, notes = @Notes, modified_datetime = getdate() where ref_code = '" + searchRefTextBox.Text + "'", con);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefCode", refCodeTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarketSegment", marketSegmentDDL.SelectedValue);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", titleTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edition", editionTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", authorTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publisher", publisherTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", yearPublishedTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", isbnTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublishedDate", publishedDateTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", notesTextBox.Text);
        cmdSubmit.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmdSubmit.Parameters.Clear();

        string msgstring = "You Have Successfully Edited a Reference";
        string content = "window.onload=function(){ alert('";
        content += msgstring;
        content += "');";
        content += "window.location='";
        content += Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        content += "';}";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SucessMessage", content, true);
    }

    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        publishedDateTextBox.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        Calendar1.Visible = false;

    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar1.Visible = true;
    }


}

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EditRef.aspx.cs" Inherits="EditRef" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: Georgia;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"  style="background-color:#E6E6FA">
    <div>

        <strong>
        <asp:Label ID="enterRefLbl" runat="server" BackColor="#0066FF" CssClass="auto-style2" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" Text="Populate Reference Data" Width="969px"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSearchRef" runat="server" Text="Search by RefCode"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitleSearch" runat="server" Text="Search by Title"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="searchRefTextBox" runat="server" Width="227px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="searchTitleTextBox" runat="server" Width="365px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPopulate" runat="server" OnClick="btnPopulate_Click" Text="Populate Fields" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblDataBelow" runat="server" BackColor="#0066FF" CssClass="auto-style3" Text="Edit Existing Reference Data Below" Width="969px"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblRefCode" runat="server" Text="Ref Code"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblExistingMarketSegment" runat="server" Text="Existing Market Segment"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblMarketSeg" runat="server" Text="New Market Segment"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="refCodeTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="existingMarketSegmentTextBox" runat="server" Width="201px"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="marketSegmentDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="market_segment_name" DataValueField="market_segment_name">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AvokaItemDevConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [market_segment_name] FROM [market_segment]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Title"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblEdition" runat="server" Text="Edition"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        </strong>
        <asp:TextBox ID="titleTextBox" runat="server" Width="580px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="editionTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAuthor" runat="server" Text="Author"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        </strong>
        <asp:TextBox ID="authorTextBox" runat="server" Width="580px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPublished" runat="server" Text="Publisher"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        </strong>
        <asp:TextBox ID="publisherTextBox" runat="server" Width="580px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>
        <asp:Label ID="lblYearPub" runat="server" Text="Year Published"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblIsbn" runat="server" Text="ISBN"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        </strong>
        <asp:TextBox ID="yearPublishedTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="isbnTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
        <br />
        <strong>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPublishedDate" runat="server" Text="Published Date"></asp:Label>
        </strong>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="publishedDateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="25px" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-datepicker[1].png" Width="19px" ForeColor="#FF6666" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#003399" Height="200px" Width="220px">
            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" Height="1px" />
            <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" Height="25px" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
        </asp:Calendar>
        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>
        <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" runat="server" Text="Notes(Use NO line breaks)"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        </strong>
        <asp:TextBox ID="notesTextBox" runat="server" Width="580px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" BackColor="#0066FF" CssClass="auto-style1" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </strong>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't going to be a problem with the code but with the host. Ensure it has ASP .net installed and the URL is correct.

Comment: The host is hosting 6 other pages in the same solution, so I'm not sure why there would be an issue there? All other pages are functioning correctly, same host.

Comment: That's very strange, check the URL twice. The 404 error is executed before than your page, so the code should not influence that at all unless your code had a redirect to another URI and it does not.

Comment: Do you have some type of url rewrite or http handler on the solution?

Comment: I just moved the files to another webserver and it executed fine. I'm wondering if my localhost is maybe just overwhelmed by the number of pages or something. I thought it may be a visual studio 15 community issue, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Well, it loads on the web server, but throws errors on use. Very strange.

Comment: Well, if you changed the host then the environment will not be the same, maybe the page does not have access to the database.

Comment: redirected the connection string to a db the server has access too, and again, the page is getting a 404. One of the pages works, so it seems pretty clear some issue was caused when copying the files. Any other ideas? it is telling me it cant see the file, when i look at the location it's pointing to, the file is absolutely there.

Comment: Hmmm, may be a permission problem? Check if the ApplicationPool user has the necessary rights to access all the hosted files.

Comment: it's using sql server auth, the apppool, and all the site are using the same webconfig file. That can't be the issue if all the other sites in the same file are working correctly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The AppPool uses a concrete user, usually "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool", if that user doesn't have the rights to access the .aspx file then it will cause that error, check the file permissions to ensure it has enough privileges as when you copy or modify the files those can change.

Comment: it's using an apppool I built, I can say with assurity it's not an apppool issue. Security is exactly the same across all files, permissions are the same across all files.

Comment: I renamed the file is VS to the same name it already was, and for whatever reason, it works now. But now I'm getting the same error on my web server, and IE is downloading the aspx file instead of opening it when I try and launch from the file explorer (open, open with IE). Very strange. All other pages still functiong fine, same path to them as well (aside from page name)

Comment: Just to close this up, I literally ended up doing nothing. I didn't try to access the site for about 4-5 hours, went back in and everything worked. I'm not really sure what happened or why my site didn't realize changes were made to it's pages, but it magically fixed itself.